# Spark DataFrame Word Count Per Document, Single Row per Document

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 1.5.2 and the Java API.  Is there a way to create a DataFrame containing word 
counts for each document with all the words and counts in a single row per document?

So far I've been able to use "org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode" to convert each word 
in the document text into a new Row.

I'm then able to create a new DataFrame containing each document, word and word count in multiple rows using the following code:

```
df = df.orderBy("doc_id").groupBy(df.col("doc_id"), df.col("word")).count();
```

The output:

```
+------+-----------+-----+
|doc_id|       word|count|
+------+-----------+-----+
|doc_1 |       game|    2|
|doc_1 |       life|    1|
|doc_1 |everlasting|    1|
|doc_1 |      learn|    1|
|doc_2 |    special|    1|
|doc_2 |     moment|    1|
|doc_2 |       time|    1|
|doc_3 | unexamined|    1|
|doc_3 |       life|    1|
|doc_3 |      worth|    1|
|doc_3 |       live|    1|
+------+-----------+-----+
```

How do I create a DataFrame in the following format:

```
 +------+-----------+---------------------------------+
 |doc_id|      word_counts|
 +------+-----------+------------------------------+
 |doc_1 |{game=1, learn=2, everlating=1, life=1}
 |doc_2 |{special=1, moment=2, everlating=1, time=1}
```

Thank you.  Any ideas are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use `explode` in the first place. If you start with a document per row you can use compute counts directly, for example using ML transformers. A very simple example could look this:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("doc_1", "game game life everlasting learn"),
  ("doc_2", "special moment time unexamined"),
  ("doc_3", "life worth live")
)).toDF("doc_id", "text")

val tokenizer = new Tokenizer()
  .setInputCol("text")
  .setOutputCol("words")

val tokenized = tokenizer.transform(df)

val cvModel = new CountVectorizer()
  .setInputCol("words")
  .setOutputCol("features")
  .fit(tokenized)

val counted = cvModel.transform(tokenized)
```

At this moment you already have counts per document. Keeping tokens explicitly in each row is rather wasteful but it can be done with small UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{SparseVector, Vector} 

def vectorsToMaps(vocabulary: Array[String]) = {
  udf((v: Vector) => {
    val sv = v.toSparse
    sv.indices.map(i => (vocabulary(i) -> sv(i))).toMap
  })
}

counted.select(vectorsToMaps(cvModel.vocabulary)($"features")
  .alias("freqs"))
  .show(3, false)

// +------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |freqs                                                             |
// +------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |Map(game -> 2.0, life -> 1.0, learn -> 1.0, everlasting -> 1.0)   |
// |Map(moment -> 1.0, special -> 1.0, unexamined -> 1.0, time -> 1.0)|
// |Map(life -> 1.0, live -> 1.0, worth -> 1.0)                       |
// +------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  "I wouldn't use explode in the first place" ... good point, I was so focused on getting the output into a specific format I lost focus on weather or not doing so was a good idea.  I was able to convert your first code block into working Java code but I'm struggling with converting the second section regarding the udf vectorsToMaps ... any pointers are greatly appreciated.  Ultimately, all I'm trying to do is calculate and persist the term counts for each document in order to later display the results in a word cloud. @zero323

Comment: You have to extend `UDF1<Vector, Map<String, Double>>`  where `Vector` is MLlib Vector. You'll find a basic example how to create SQL UDF [in Learning Spark repo](https://github.com/databricks/learning-spark/blob/master/src/main/java/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/java/SparkSQLTwitter.java#L50). Internally it is pretty much the same logic as in Scala. Create an empty map. For each index in vector.indices put (key, value) in the map.

Comment: @tullm If thats the case could accept the answer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop down to the RDD and use an `aggregateByKey`:

```
df.rdd
  .aggregateByKey(Map[String,Int]())
  (
    (wordMap, word) => wordMap + (word -> (1 + wordMap.getOrElse(word, 0))), 
    (wordMap1, wordMap2) => wordMap1 ++ wordMap2.map{ case(k,v) => (k -> (v + wordMap1.getOrElse(k,0))) }
  )
```

Comment: Thank you.  I found the aggregate method but do not see a aggregateByKey method.  I'm using the Java API ... 1.5.1

Comment: In java you'll need to cast to a JavaPairRDD first (which has the aggregateByKey method) -> https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD